# Function type not causing errors when I expect errors

Tags: typescript

I'm guessing I'm not doing something quite right, but I'm not sure what it is.

I'm wanting to write a type that describes a function and it's return type.

```js
type SomeFn<Output extends Record<string, any>> = ( x: Record<string, any> ) => Output
```

But when I use it, I don't get errors when I would expect them.

```js
type ExpectedOutput = { num1: number }

const testFn1: SomeFn<ExpectedOutput> = x => ( { foo: 'foo', num1: 1 } )
//                     should error, but doesn't ^^^^^^^^^^ 

const testFn2: SomeFn<ExpectedOutput> = x => {
    const data = { foo: 'foo', num1: 1 }
    return data
    //     ^^^^ should error, but doesn't
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40311

Answer (score 1):

That's because of Typescript's structural typing :

Something like this is valid in TS :

```
type SomeFn = () => { num1: 1 }    
const testFn1: SomeFn = () => ({ num1: 1, foo: 'bar' })
```

What you might want is Exact types but [it's an open ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) at the moment.